Why is `flask migrate` not recognizing models
I have a project with the following structure in the src directory:
├── migrations
├── .envrc
├── requirements.txt
├── alembic.ini
├── __init__.py
├── flask_app
│   ├── model.py (db and migrate objects declared here)
│   ├── app.py (from .model import db, migrate)
│   ├── landing
│   │   ├── landing_templates
│   │   ├── models.py (from flask_app.model import db)
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── user
│   │   ├── user_templates
│   │   ├── models.py (from flask_app.model import db)
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── templates
├── alembic
├── run_flask_app.py

When I run the line below while in the src directory (which is in my python path):
flask --app  'flask_app.app:create_app("flask_app.config.DevelopmentConfig")' db migrate
Flask Migrate doesn't detect any models and no migration script is generated. (ie INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.).
However, when I change the imports in the models.py files to from src.flask_app.model import db the models are detected and a migration script is generated.
When I deploy the src directory contents are deployed, but not the the directory itself, so I don't think the the from src.flask_app.model import db is an option.  I had used this structure in another project and used Flask_Script for migrations, but Flask_Script is no longer maintained.  I'd like to move to the modern tool, but I can't figure out what my problem is.

Well, changing the import in app.py to from flask_app.model import db, migrate solved this.  I think it made the names space between the app and the models the same.  However, I still don't know why importing from src.flask_app.model import db in the model files worked.
